# Abel's test for uniform convergence in Fourier series

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series, uniform-convergence

In Abel's test for uniform convergence, we wite the terms of the series as $u_n(x)=a_n f_n(x)$ and there is a condition which says that the functions $f_n(x)$ should be monotonic, in mathematical notation it is 
$$
f_{n+1}(x) \leq f_n(x)
$$
Up to this point, things are fine, but when I am trying to look for uniform convergence in Fourier series I am unable to satisfy this condition. As an example in the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(nx)}{n^2}
$$
$f_n(x)=\cos(nx)$ which are not monotonic.
[clear from this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i52LD.jpg)

Are the conditions for Abel's test are different for series that contain sinusoidal terms?

Ref: Arfken 6th Edition page 351

Comment: Maybe the confusion arises from the fact that this type of convergence follows from Abel summation (or summation by parts), so people tend to refer to it informally using Abel's name, though in this case the method is also known as Dirichlet's test

Comment: Abel’s test can be used to prove uniform convergence of a series $\sum f_n(x) g_n(x)$ when $f_n(x)$ is monotonic and uniformly bounded and $\sum g_n(x)$ is uniformly convergent.

Comment: It can't be used here but Dirichlet's test can -- on restricted sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To just consider the question of uniform convergence with regard to your example, note that

$$\left|\frac{\cos nx}{n^2} \right| \leqslant \frac{1}{n^2}$$

Therefore, the series is absolutely and uniformly convergent for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ by the Weierstrass M-test. Nevertheless, Abel’s test is not applicable.

Consider a similar example $\sum \frac{\cos nx}{n}$, which actually is conditionally convergent and the Weierstrass test cannot be applied.  Abel's test is not helpful since two conditions are violated in that $\cos nx$ is not monotonic and $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ is not convergent. Furthermore, even though $\frac{1}{n}$ is monotonic, the series $\sum \cos nx $ is not uniformly (nor even pointwise) convergent.

The series is not uniformly convergent for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, but we can show that convergence is uniform on intervals that do not have $2k\pi$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ as a limit point. To this end, we can use the related [**Dirichlet's test**](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_Test_for_Uniform_Convergence).

Consider, for example, the interval $[a,\pi]$ where $0 < a < \pi$. We see that $\frac{1}{n}$ is nonincreasing and uniformly convergent to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. Additionally, we have

$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^m \cos nx  \right| =  \left|\frac{\sin \frac{mx}{2} \cos \frac{(m+1)x}{2} }{\sin \frac{x}{2}}\right| \leqslant \frac{1}{\sin \frac{a}{2} }$$

Since these partial sums are uniformly bounded for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in [a,\pi]$ we have uniform convergence.